# show a div if all multiple options are selected

Tags: jquery

I see lots of questions and answers on how to show a div if select options are chosen or if a certain select is chosen, but I can't figure out how to make a div show if multiple selects are changed.

I have three select boxes, and each one is set to a default. What I need to do is if all three have been changed, then show a div.

```
<select id="select1" class="select">
<option selected="selected" class="default_selected" disabled>Thing</option>
<option id="a" value="1">option one</option>
<option id="b" value="2">option two</option>
<option id="c" value="3">option three</option>
</select>

<select id="select2" class="select">
<option selected="selected" class="default_selected" disabled>Thing</option>
<option id="a" value="1">option one</option>
<option id="b" value="2">option two</option>
<option id="c" value="3">option three</option>
</select>

<select id="select3" class="select">
<option selected="selected" class="default_selected" disabled>Thing</option>
<option id="a" value="1">option one</option>
<option id="b" value="2">option two</option>
<option id="c" value="3">option three</option>
</select>

<div class="hidden">show if all three selects are changed to something.</div>
```

I've tried:

```
        $('.select').on('change',function(){
            if($('.select').find(":selected").attr('class')=='default_select'){
                alert('test');
            }
            else{
                $('.hidden').removeClass('hidden').show();  
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try, adding a class using `addClass`  in the `change` event, then check it the number of changed elements is the same as the total.

HTML:

```
<select id="select1" class="selection">
    <option selected="selected" class="default_selected" disabled>Thing</option>
    <option id="a" value="1">option one</option>
    <option id="b" value="2">option two</option>
    <option id="c" value="3">option three</option>
</select>
<select id="select2" class="selection">
    <option selected="selected" class="default_selected" disabled>Thing</option>
    <option id="a" value="1">option one</option>
    <option id="b" value="2">option two</option>
    <option id="c" value="3">option three</option>
</select>
<select id="select3" class="selection">
    <option selected="selected" class="default_selected" disabled>Thing</option>
    <option id="a" value="1">option one</option>
    <option id="b" value="2">option two</option>
    <option id="c" value="3">option three</option>
</select>
<div class="hidden">show if all three selects are changed to something.</div>
```

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".selection").change(function () {
        $(this).addClass("changed");
        if ($(".selection").length === $(".changed").length) {
            $(".hidden").show();
        }
    });
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/IrvinDominin/tQu2b/

Comment: Great! This works perfect. It's simple, and easy to understand. Thank you Irvin.

Answer (score 1):

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/cse_tushar/R9QuC/)

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.hidden').hide();
    $('select[id^="select"]').change(function () {
        var len = $('select[id^="select"] option:selected').filter(function () {
            return this.value != 'Thing';
        }).length;
        if(len == 3){
            $('.hidden').show();
        }
    });
});
```

Refrences

[^ attribute starts with selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/)

[.filter()](http://api.jquery.com/filter/)

Answer (score 0):

May be this ll help you

```
$( ".default_selected" ).change(function() {
if( $('select[.default_selected]').text()!="Thing")
        {
        $("div[.hidden]").show();
        }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var $selects= $('select').each(function(){
   /* store original value */
    $(this).data('orig', this.value);
}).change(function(){
  /* filter out changed selects and get qty*/
    var numChanged= $selects.filter(function(){
        return $(this).data('orig') != this.value;
    }).length;
        $('.hidden')[ numChanged == 3 ? 'show' : 'hide']();    
});
```

<kbd>**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/M26hc/)**</kbd>

Answer (score -1):

Just check if the values compare with `option:selected` value.

Comment: Can the person who -1 this explain why?